# Asking employer of possibility to be hired full time after second internship

Tags: internship, fulltime

I had an internship in a company last year over the summer, and asked my supervisor to return there for another internship, for which he agreed and said he would love to have me back to continue working on the work I did the previous year.

This internship is in a different city from where I live, and I intend to move there. Before I do my internship in Summer of 2018, I want to email the supervisor and ask if it would be possible to continue working after my summer internship is over, either as part time or full time. (given that by this point I would have completed 2 internships there)

I want to ask if I will be able to continue work there to support myself financially (also stating that I also want to work there afterwards because I love what I do there), or if I would have to find other work before my internship is over and get a head start on the job search.

Is this something that would be acceptable to ask at this point, or should I wait until I am actually working there before bringing it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this something that would be acceptable to ask at this point, or should I wait until I am actually working there before bringing it up?

I think it's fine to ask, though I doubt he will be able to give you a definitive answer right away.  You may want to phrase your question in terms of likelihood, e.g.,

> "Assuming you and the rest of the team are pleased with my performance, do you think there's a good chance I might be eligible for a full time position at the conclusion of the internship? I ask because I want to make sure I have a solid plan in place for when that time comes."

Answer (score 2):

Sure, no harm in asking!

> Is this something that would be acceptable to ask at this point, or should I wait until I am actually working there before bringing it up?

Ask if it's a *possibility* right away, but you'll likely need to wait to get a definite answer.

> Hi Bob,
>
> I'm looking forward to starting the internship with you next year to carry on working on `x`. I've been thinking a bit further into the future, and wondered if there's any possibility that there may be a part / full time position that I could apply for after the internship is over?

You may not get a definite yes, but you may (unfortunately) get a definite no - and if this is the case, then at least you know early on that you're going to have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

**Dont get ahead of yourself.**

You asked for another **internship** which is exactly what you got. For all I care, they themselves may not know if they want/can employ you long-term after this.

So:

- Go on with your internship and prove to them your worth and why they **need** you.
- Check back with them a few weeks before the internship ends to see if they re satisfied with your work & if they re able/can afford to hire you. If it doesnt go through, you had another round of valuable junior experience earned and you have enough time to job-hunt for your next move after this.

Comment: To whoever is downvoting, I m always up for corrections and different POVs. Feel free to chime in, I dont perceive my proposal as out of topic or unrealistic to warrant the minuses.